# URL mapping of servlets and JSP files with Tomcat and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have a web application project in Eclipse that is configured to deploy to a local Tomcat server. Let's call the web application **Blah**. Here are two questions -- I must be missing something very simple, but I can't find an easy way to change these settings within Eclipse without fiddling with the Tomcat configuration files.

1.
When the application is deployed, the URL I can use to browse to some servlet/JSP is `localhost:port/Blah/servlet`. I would like to get rid of the **Blah** prefix.

2.
I would like to set up redirects for some JSP files to "hide" the .jsp extension. For example, I'd like `localhost:port/login` to be served by `localhost:port/login.jsp`, preferably without the browser seeing a 30x redirect status code.

3.
I would like to set the default URL, i.e. `localhost:port/`, to redirect to a particular JSP or servlet (again, preferably without issuing a redirect status code).

Any help, including links to relevant resources, would be greatly appreciated. Please note that I am looking for a way to configure these things from within Eclipse, if possible. (If not possible, I would like to do the minimal amount of changes to the scary Tomcat XML files.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This means that you need to deploy your application as the root application. It's easily done by naming your war file ROOT.WAR (or your exploded war directory ROOT), or by [defining a context for your web app](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) with an empty string as the `path` attribute.
2. Then you don't want a redirect, but a forward. Or you simply want to map the JSP (which IS a servlet) to a given path. Define a servlet and a servlet mapping in the web.xml file, as you would for a servlet class, but use `<jsp-file>` instead of `<servlet-class>`.
3. This is done using the `<welcome-file-list>` element in the web.xml.

Comment: Thanks, these are the kind of things I was afraid I would have to do. Still, good to have a confirmation and thanks for the link. I will mark as answer if there are no better suggestions :-)

Comment: Why are you afraid? Is adding a few lines of XML in a file, with auto-completion, such a frightening task?

Comment: Obviously I am saying "afraid" figuratively. However, when working with Eclipse, I want to minimize the changes I have to make to configuration files. For example, I prefer to add a servlet through the Eclipse wizard rather than add a class to my project and then (separately) configure it as a servlet. I see it as a matter of personal preference, and have stated it explicitly in my question...

Comment: You can use the wizard for creating a servlet, and choose "use an existiing class or JSP". The rest will need you to use your keyboard.